# use of pow in python

Tags: python, pow

I am confused by the following Python expression. The variables `term1` and `Pin` are computed prior to the call:

```
term2 = pow(pow(Pin,2) - term1,0.5)
```

I understand that `pow(Pin,2) = Pin**2`, but I do not get what `- term1, 0.5` does.

Comment: term2 is the square root of (Pin^2 - term1) i.e. (Pin^2 - term1)^0.5.

Comment: Which is `sqrt(Pin**2 - term1)` ... and maybe should be written that way instead ...

Answer (score 2):

It's two separate calls. The inner pow is equivalent to `Pin ** 2` (as you determined), with the outer call equivalent to `(Pin ** 2 - term1) ** 0.5` or `math.sqrt(Pin ** 2 - term1)` (exponentiating to the `0.5` power is equivalent to taking the square root of a number).

Answer (score 1):

It is just a shorter, more concise way to write expressions:

```
power_1 = pow(Pin, 2) 
power_1 = power_1 - term1 

term2 = pow(power1, 0.5)
```